# google maps v3 change size of infowindow

Tags: google-maps-api-3, infowindow

I would like to set the size of an infowindow to fit the content inside. The standard infowindow is too wide I tried to use maxWidth but it doesn't seem to work. What is the best way to resize an infowindow?

see code:

```
    window.setContent( inspStates[i].name+ "<br/>"+"total: "+inspStates[i].totalInsp+ "<br/>"+ info);
```

the information that will be displayed in the bubble looks like this( \n means next line)

NY \ntotal 60 \n2009: 10 \n2010: 20 \n2011: 30

Answer (score 14):

What you want to do is replace the "standard" Googlemaps infoWindow with your own, and put your content into it. Once you replace the standard GM infoWindow, you have a lot of latitude to work with. What I did is this:

Add a new style ID called #infoWindow, and set its width.

```
#infoWindow {
    width: 150px;
}
```

Outside of any functions within my Javascript, I create a new infoWindow:

```
var infoWindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow();
```

Create a new var within the function that sets the information displayed by the marker(s), and set its value to the content:

```
var html = '<div id="infoWindow">';
html += 'NY<br />total 60<br />2009: 10<br />2010: 20<br />2011: 30';
html +='</div>';
```

Call the createMarker function using the location information you would have created elsewhere, and include the html var as one of the arguments:

```
var marker = createMarker(point,name,html);
```

The createMarker function you would declare elsewhere, which would bring all of the information together, display the marker on your map, and display the information above when it's clicked on:

```
function createMarker(latlng,name,html) {
    var contentString = html;
    var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
        position: latlng,
        map: map,
        title: name
        });

    google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'click', function() {
        infoWindow.setContent(contentString); 
        infoWindow.open(map,marker);
        });
}
```

Comment: where should the style id be declared? inside or outside the script

Comment: With the rest of your CSS, either on the page or in an external stylesheet.

Answer (score 9):

Just so everyone is clear, if they stumble on this thread.

All you need to do is set the height and width of a container in the your info window content.

You don't need to override google classes and you don't need to get overly complicated about this.

```
var contentString = '<div class="map-info-window">'+
  '<h1>My Info Window</h1>'+
  '<p>Hello World</p>'+
  '</div>';

var infowindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow({
      content: contentString,   });
```

In my css I have this:

```
.map-info-window {
    width:200px;
    height:200px;
}
```

That's it. That's all you need to do to set the width of a Google Maps InfoWindow.

Answer (score 9):

For me this CSS works fine:

```
.gm-style-iw {
  width: 324px !important;
  height: 120px !important;
}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot .... I was about to use a different plugin to change width height of my infowindow

Answer (score 2):

please take a look at following API references and examples:

Google Map V3 Examples: 
https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/examples/

Google Map V3 API Ref: 
https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/reference#MapOptions

Comment: For the maxWidth see: https://google-developers.appspot.com/maps/documentation/javascript/examples/infowindow-simple-max

Comment: How does this help as an answer?

Answer (score 1):

To set the size of the bubble info-window inside a google map it's enough to add the following  css in your CSS file:

```
.gmap-popup {
  max-width:204px;
  max-height:110px;
}
```

Adapted from [this discussion](https://drupal.org/node/63085).

Answer (score 0):

JFrancis answers is the right one, just don't forget to add "!important" in your CSS when you set the width! This might look like a minor thing, but if you don't do it, your CSS will simply get overwritten!

```
#infoWindow {
    width: 150px !important;
}
```